# Log4j Issue while using RollingFileAppender,maxsize,maxbackupindex and close

Tags: java, logging, log4j, apache-camel

I have used the `RollingFileAppender` and logger class to print the logs to a file,i do not have a separate configuration file.

```
public void logBIHAuditMessage(String message, Level level, String Location) {

    try {
        RollingFileAppender fileAppender = new RollingFileAppender(new PatternLayout(
                "%d{DATE} %p %M %m %n"), "C:\\Logfiles\\Audit.log", true);

        fileAppender.setMaxFileSize("5MB");
        fileAppender.setMaxBackupIndex(5);
        fileAppender.activateOptions();
        LOG.addAppender(fileAppender);
        LOG.info(message);
        fileAppender.close();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

The `logBIHAuditMessage` is called from multiple places in Apache camel application.

I am getting below error because of the use of `fileAppender.close();`

> 10:36:39,715 ERROR [stderr] (Camel (camel-9) thread #20 - JmsConsumer[BIH_A1_Req_INHQ]) log4j:ERROR Attempted to append to closed appender named [null].

If I do not close the file appender then the same log is getting printed multiple times.

If I do not use the synchronized keyword also some of the logs are getting printed multiple times could you please tell me what might be the issue?

Answer (score 0):

you have two `log4j.properties` available in the Log4J.

You keep one in classpath and other being loaded may be programatically using `PropertyConfigurator.configure(..)).` You can remove any of them.

or, You can override it by following code.

```
BasicConfigurator.resetConfiguration();
PropertyConfigurator.configure(props);
```

Comment: Hi,
Thanks,i have removed the syncronized keyword and have added the configuration for reset it is printing only once. 

but  getting the below error while using fileAppender.close();

15:25:14,434 ERROR [stderr] (Camel (camel-22) thread #29 - JmsConsumer[BIH_A1_Req_INHQ]) log4j:ERROR Attempted to append to closed appender named [null]. still getting same error.